# Data Annotations not including data- attributes on form elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, unobtrusive-validation

I must be missing something totally obvious here.  I just started with a clean project - MVC 3/Razor - and I'm attempting to configure unobtrusive JavaScript validation.  Everything I can find says I just need to add the data annotations to my model, and set UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled to true in the web.config, and everything should work.  The problem I'm having is that when I look and the rendered source, my input field doesn't even have the data-val property.  Here's what I've got:

```
public class PersonModel
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And in the controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new Models.PersonModel());
    }
```

And in the View:

```
@model ValidationTest.Models.PersonModel
...
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName)
```

I would expect to see an input tag rendered that includes the data-val attribute, but instead I'm only seeing:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="">
```

Am I missing a simple setting somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the implemetation:
Only render attributes if unobtrusive client-side validation is enabled, and then only if we've never rendered validation for a field with this name in this form. Also, if there's no form context, then we can't render the attributes (we'd have no  to attach them to).

So I guess you need to put your EditorFor inside a Form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName)
}
```

Comment: That was it! Oddly, I had put a simple `<form action="">` tag in there just to test, but that didn't seem to trigger it.  Once I wrapped it with the `Html.BeginForm()` it worked.  Thanks!